# How to properly add external php files in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a small websockets chat written, the php part is just 2 files, `server.php` and `Chat.php`, they are both inside a `bin` folder and depend on `ratchet` and some other libraries which I downloaded to the laravel installation via composer.

server.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require 'Chat.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 8080);

$server->run();
```

Chat.php

```
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

    protected $clients;

    function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) 
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) 
        {
            if ($client !== $conn ) {
                $client->send($msg); 
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'the following error occured: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $conn->close();
    }

}
```

Now, I have that `bin` folder inside the laravel root, and so I am able to start the server since the `server.php` is looking for dependencies in vendor one level up, but what I wanna do is use all the laravel goodies within these files, especially within `Chat.php`.

So now for example if I write `use DB` in `Chat.php` it gives an error (which I understand, it has no way of knowing laravel), so my question is how do I include this bin folder and its files so that I can use all the laravel goodies within them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to manually load vendor/autoload.php because laravel does that for you.
First you have to create folder inside your YourLaravelRoot/app dir(Let's name that as Services). Then move chat.php into that, rename it to ChatService.php(Change class name also to ChatService) or any appropriate name(reccomanded to ends with xxxxService so it's easier to identify) and namespace it as `namespace App\Services;`(Assumming that your app name is App).Namespacing correctly is important otherwise you have to manually loads it throught composer.json .Then create a artisan command and move content of server.php into handle method inside command(Let's name it ServerCommand.php). Add `use App\Services\ChatService as Chat;`. Register the command in Kernal.php on app/console That's it. Now you should be able to access any laravel facade inside ChatService

Summary:

YourLaravelProject

-app

--Console

Kernal.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\ServerCommand::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
    }
}
```

---Commands

----ServerCommand.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Services\ChatService as Chat;

class ServerCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'server:run';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 8080);
        $server->run();
    }
}
```

--Services

---ChatService.php

```phpl
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
/**
*  
*/
class ChatService implements MessageComponentInterface {
{
    protected $clients;

    function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) 
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) 
        {
            if ($client !== $conn ) {
                $client->send($msg); 
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'the following error occured: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Execute command `php artisan server:run`

Comment: I guess you meant app/http/controllers, anyway I made a `ChatController` with this namespace: `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` and I made `chatserver,php` in the root folder with this using statement: `use App\Http\Controllers\ChatController;`, however when I run it from console I get this: ` Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ChatController' not fou
nd in C:\wamp\www\laraveltesting\chatserver.php:13
`

Comment: To run your server, you have call to server.php. So it should be in a controller. And chat.php is just a helper class to run the server, so it's a service for server.php.  that's why I suggested above structure.

Comment: What's the point of making the route? I'm supposed to call the server.php script from the console not from the browser. So when I try to run ServerController from the command line I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in C:\wamp\www\laraveltesting\app\Http\Controllers\ServerController.php on line 14

Comment: Either way I don't think that;s how it should be, the server shouldn't be a controller but chat should be a controller because I want to add Laravel stuff there, such as db communication.

Comment: I've made some progress, but still cant use DB. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673289/laravel-5-class-db-not-found

Comment: Actually if you want to use laravel facades you have to enter the request lifecycle(https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/lifecycle).

Comment: I get `Class App\Console\Commands\ServerCommand does not exist`

Comment: How did you create the ServerCommand.php? manually or using php artisan make:console? if you did manually please run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: It works man thank you so much. Just a side note, you called the file `Server.php` in your answer, seems to have to be `ServerCommand.php`

Comment: Fixed it, laravel has specific naming conventions. that's why I change it to ServerCommand since it's a command. Anyway glad to help you. Good luck