# Laravel 5 - Class 'DB' not found

Tags: laravel-5

I have `ChatController` located in `app/http/controllers` like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use DB;

class ChatController extends Controller implements MessageComponentInterface {

    protected $clients;

    function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) 
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) 
        {
            if ($client !== $conn )
                $client->send($msg); 

            DB::table('messages')->insert(
                ['message' => $msg]
            );
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'the following error occured: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $conn->close();
    }

}
```

And I have `chatserver.php` file in the root like so:

```
<?php
require  'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use App\Http\Controllers\ChatController;


$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new ChatController()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

If I remove

```
DB::table('messages')->insert(
                    ['message' => $msg]
                );
```

from the `ChatController` and start `chatserver.php` it works, but if I don't remove it then the server starts but as soon as I send a message I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\wamp\www\laraveltesting\app\Http\Controllers\ChatController.php:31
```

Why won't it use DB? I am extending the laravel controller.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh same crap

Answer (score 10):

This one is better

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Or you can use a slash('/') before DB like below

```
/DB::table('messages')->insert(
                ['message' => $msg]
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

instead of

```
use DB;
```

Comment: I get this: the following error occured: A facade root has not been set. - either way, I don't get why use DB isn't enough since I am extending the controller.

Answer (score 2):

As previously advised First use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

then go /bootstrap/app.php and uncomment

```
$app->withFacades();
```

Answer (score 1):

for Laravel 5 and up simply just use this

```
use DB;
```

instead of

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

which is use for Laravel 4 version

Answer (score 1):

change use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; to Use DB;

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your test class file (before the `class` keyword) so your test can find the location of the Laravel application and create a new app.

```
if (!isset($app)) {
    $app = new \Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
          // E.g. if the current dir is app/tests/Unit/
          // Your path may differ
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../../')
    );
}
```

And in the test methods where you want to use DB, add `global $app`

```
public function testSomething()
{
    global $app;
    //
}
```